# Why is a linefeed char added to the http response?

Tags: ajax, string, http, newline, httpresponse

I do this ajax request:

```
 var response = $.ajax({
    url: 'product/add', 
    data: $("#formAddNewRow").serialize(),
    type: "POST",
    success: function() {
    var id = response.responseText;     
                        }            
                      });
```

`'product/add'` is a symfony action that does some stuff. the action's view is what gets returned, for testing purpose that file looks like this:

```
<?php

 echo "test";

?>
```

When I look at `response.responseText` right after `success`, I get `"test\n"`. I would have expected just `"test"`.

This is what a Response Header looks like:

```
Date    Thu, 22 Sep 2011 15:17:45 GMT
Server  Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.5
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma  no-cache
Content-Length  5
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=99
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Somewhere else I do an ajax request to `url: 'product/update'`, it's view being exactly the same code (`<?php echo "test"; ?>`). But in this case `response.responseText`equals `"test"`, which is what I expect - there is no \n added. 
In that case, a Response Header looks like:

```
Date    Thu, 22 Sep 2011 15:27:20 GMT
Server  Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.5
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma  no-cache
Content-Length  4
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=99
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
```

I have not the slightest idea, why `response.responseText` whouldn't be the same in both cases.

Why does a newline character get added to `response.responseText`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that there is a linefeed character after the final ?>

Unless I am actually putting PHP inside a HTML page, I always leave off the last ?>. It isn't necessary, and tends to cause problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

Because [it's part of the HTTP protocol](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html)?

```
   Response      = Status-Line               ; Section 6.1
                   *(( general-header        ; Section 4.5
                    | response-header        ; Section 6.2
                    | entity-header ) CRLF)  ; Section 7.1
                   CRLF
                   [ message-body ]          ; Section 7.2
```

Comment: Well, I guess `responseText` is referring to the message-body, isn't it? I can't see a linefeed there.

Comment: @Gert S, yah, it does seem like there should be no CRLF after the message body. If anything, you should probably trim any leading/trailing white space from the `responseText`.